# Как реализовать список со значками на андроид в RelativeLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Мне необходимо реализовать динамически реализуемый список ListView с различными значками. Реализация с использованием ListActivity у меня прекрасно работает, но теперь необходимо реализовать пролистываемый список в RelativeLayout, но при этом если использовать ListActivity то у меня каждый новый элемент списка со значком будет содержаться в новом RelativeLayout. Как мне сделать так чтобы у меня был один RelativeLayout внутри которого бы содержался мой список, то есть использовать в классе extends Activity?
Может есть готовые примеры?

Ниже разметка Layout который мне необходим:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:margin_left="15dp"
    android:margin_right="15dp"
    android:margin_Top="15dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Ниже код класса наполняющего содержимым. Вся загвоздка в создании адаптера:

```
package ...

import ...

public class ListViewWithIconsActivity extends ListActivity {

    // определяем массив типа String
    final String[] names = new String[] { "Имя", "Имя", "Имя",
            "Имя", "Имя", "Имя", "Имя", "Имя", "Имя",
            "Имя", "Имя", "Имя", "Имя" };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,
                R.id.name, names));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, selection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: а положить ListView в RelativeLayout что мешает? Просто в onCreate инициализировать ListView по id и работать с ним и в итоге наследоваться от обычного Activity. Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: Я так и делаю по стандартной схеме, но каждый элемент ListView создается в новом RelativeLayout. Я же напрямую в разметке ListView не создаю, я создаю LinearLayout в котором есть ImageView и TextView
, и затем  из него делаю список. Может что то я не так понимаю, но по другому список со значками я не умею создавать!)

Comment: я думаю вам подойдет ответ из этого вопроса
http://hashcode.ru/questions/239299/android-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Можно конечно просто динамически создавать при помощи кода столько элементов, сколько надо, и добавлять их в ваш RelativeLayout, но это извращение высшей степени, достойное лучших индусских говнокодеров, по этому я предполагаю, что вы не очень правильно выразились. Можете привести фрагменты ваших layout что бы мы тут могли понять, что вы пытаетесь сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать SimpleAdapter как тут http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/listview/icon_twotext_simpleadapter.php

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно включить пример кода, объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки и т. п.

Comment: Этого недостаточно для того, чтобы сформировать ответ. Максимум комментарий.